# SQLite DB not been created

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I tried to copy all the phone call logs to database created and the code is running well, but there is no `.db` file genertated in following package,

```
data/data/your.application.package/databases/
```

Class code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.CallLog;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class logs extends BroadcastReceiver
 {
    SQLiteDatabase calllog;
    String get_number, get_type, get_duration, Current_time, get_date,logTypecode;
    Handler hand = new Handler();

Cursor cursor;
LocalDb dbex;
ContentValues cm;
int logtype;

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
    if(intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"))
    {
        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE))
        {
            hand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String number=android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER;
                String date=android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE;
                String type=android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE;
                String duration=android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION;

                Log.i("ddd", ""+duration);
                Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

                if(cursor.moveToNext()){
                    cursor.moveToPrevious();
                    while(cursor.moveToNext()){

                    get_number=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(number));
                    get_date=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(date));
                    get_type=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(type));
                    get_duration=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(duration));
                    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-mm  HH:mm:ss");
                    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                    logtype=Integer.parseInt(get_type);
                    Current_time=DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                    Log.i("ddd", ""+get_duration);



                    try
                    {
                    switch (logtype) {
                    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                        logTypecode="O";
                           dbex.open();
                           Log.i("ddd", ""+get_duration);
                           cm.put("number",get_number);
                           cm.put("type",get_type);
                           cm.put("time",Current_time);
                           cm.put("duration",get_duration);
                           cm.put("date",get_date);
                           dbex.insert_values("Logs",cm);
                           dbex.close();

                                break;

                        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                            logTypecode="I";
                               dbex.open();
                               cm.put("number",get_number);
                               cm.put("type",get_type);
                               cm.put("time",Current_time);
                               cm.put("duration",get_duration);
                               cm.put("date",get_date);
                               dbex.insert_values("Logs",cm);
                               dbex.close();

                                    break;

                        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                            logTypecode="M";
                               dbex.open();
                               cm.put("number",get_number);
                               cm.put("type",get_type);
                               cm.put("time",Current_time);
                               cm.put("duration",get_duration);
                               cm.put("date",get_date);
                               dbex.insert_values("Logs",cm);
                               dbex.close();

                                    break;
                                }
                            }


                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }


                    }
                }
                    cursor.close();

                    }
                },2000);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

DBAdapter Helper Class for logs.java

```
public class LocalDb {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=3;
private DatabaseHelper dbhelp;
public SQLiteDatabase mdb;
static final String DATABASE_NAME ="DBImage";
static final String Logs =" Logs";

Context context;

private static final String Table1 = "create table if not exists " + Logs + "( id  integer primary key autoincrement ," + "number text,type text,time text,duration text,date text )";

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(Table1);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+Table1);

    }


}

public LocalDb(Context ctx){
    this.context=ctx;
}

public LocalDb open() throws SQLException{

    dbhelp=new DatabaseHelper(context);
    mdb=dbhelp.getWritableDatabase();

    return this;

}
public void close(){
    dbhelp.close();
}

public long insert_values(String Table,ContentValues initialvalues){


    return mdb.insert(Table, null, initialvalues);

}
public Cursor fetchMainLists(){

    String sql = "SELECT id,number,type,time,duration,date FROM Logs ";
    Cursor cur = mdb.rawQuery(sql, null);
    return cur ;

}
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.ekp.call_log_db"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INPUT_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <receiver android:name="logs" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver><activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat

```
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:544)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at com.ekp.call_log.logs.onReceive(logs.java:35)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:1794)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2400(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:981)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-22 15:18:29.965: E/Database(1676):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Database-not inserting value into DB table

```
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202): close() was never explicitly called on database '/data/data/com.ekp.call_log_db/databases/DBImage' 
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202): android.database.sqlite.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1847)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:820)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:854)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:847)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:544)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:203)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at com.ekp.call_log_db.LocalDb.open(LocalDb.java:56)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at com.ekp.call_log_db.logs$1.run(logs.java:46)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-22 16:53:55.145: E/Database(30202):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that your `BroadcastReceiver`'s `onReceive` method is actually called?

Comment: You could insert `Log` statement like `Log.d(TAG, "onReceive")` into your `onReceive` method to see if it is actually called. Because the database will not be created until it is accessed for the first time.

Comment: Okay, there are a couple of things going wrong. First: I can't see that you are actually passing a `Context` into the `LocalDb` object in your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: can you please correct my codes...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below Receiver code instead of your Broadcast Receiver code, it will solve your problem.

```
public class logs extends BroadcastReceiver {
    SQLiteDatabase calllog;
    String get_number, get_type, get_duration, Current_time, get_date,logTypecode;
    Handler hand = new Handler();
    Cursor cursor;
    LocalDb dbex;
    ContentValues cm;
    int logtype;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        dbex = new LocalDb(context);

        String state=intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                hand.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        String number=android.provider.CallLog.Calls.NUMBER;
                        String date=android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE;
                        String type=android.provider.CallLog.Calls.TYPE;
                        String duration=android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DURATION;

                        Log.i("ddd", ""+duration);
                        dbex.open();
                        Cursor cursor=context.getContentResolver().query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

                        if(cursor.moveToNext()) {
                            cursor.moveToPrevious();

                            while(cursor.moveToNext()) {

                                get_number=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(number));
                                get_date=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(date));
                                get_type=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(type));
                                get_duration=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(duration));
                                SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-mm  HH:mm:ss");
                                dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                                logtype=Integer.parseInt(get_type);
                                Current_time=DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date());
                                Log.i("ddd", ""+get_duration);
                                try {
                                    switch (logtype) {
                                        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                                            logTypecode="O";
                                            dbex.open();
                                            Log.i("ddd", ""+get_duration);
                                            cm.put("number",get_number);
                                            cm.put("type",get_type);
                                            cm.put("time",Current_time);
                                            cm.put("duration",get_duration);
                                            cm.put("date",get_date);
                                            dbex.insert_values("Logs",cm);
                                            dbex.close();

                                            break;

                                        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                                            logTypecode="I";
                                            dbex.open();
                                            cm.put("number",get_number);
                                            cm.put("type",get_type);
                                            cm.put("time",Current_time);
                                            cm.put("duration",get_duration);
                                            cm.put("date",get_date);
                                            dbex.insert_values("Logs",cm);
                                            dbex.close();

                                            break;

                                        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                                            logTypecode="M";
                                            dbex.open();
                                            cm.put("number",get_number);
                                            cm.put("type",get_type);
                                            cm.put("time",Current_time);
                                            cm.put("duration",get_duration);
                                            cm.put("date",get_date);
                                            dbex.insert_values("Logs",cm);
                                            dbex.close();

                                            break;
                                    }
                                } catch(Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        cursor.close();
                        dbex.close();

                    }
                },2000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code solved my inital problem with database, but its not inserting values into DB table

Comment: @ekp This is not good because your question is solved now and if you want to more information then post another question or tell me here with full information.

Comment: @ekp First accept my this answer and put full error logcat with new question, so it will take more attention and give me link also.

Comment: @ekp Update this line static final String Logs =" Logs"; and remove space from beginning of " Logs", and try.

Comment: still not inserting values into DB table

Comment: @ekp Please post another question with full description and error logcat also.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004199/its-not-inserting-call-logs-into-db-table